# Drawing custom shapes with THREE BufferGeometry - shape is see through depending on angle

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I am working with THREE.js and BufferGeometry to create a view of a set of points based on an image. Currently, I have the following:

[image: Example problem]
[image: other angle]

As can be seen, the "object" that I have constructed has faces that can only be viewed from the opposite side as intended.

I have constructed my BufferGeometry with the a set of points with a corresponding array of normals, implemented like so (assuming that verts and norms are valid):

```
   vertices = Float32Array.from(verts)
   normals = Float32Array.from(norms)

   // Make new geometry
   geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

   geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))
   geometry.setAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3))
   material  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

   geometry.computeVertexNormals()

   scene.add(mesh)
```

As you can see from trying to add the array of normals, I have tried adding normals in which all are (0,1,0). Without `geometry.computeVertexNormals()`, this still results in none of the faces being solid/behaving correctly. With such, the result in the image is generated.

What could be causing the solid to behave as such?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got correct order of vertices in faces? Looks like it's clockwise, whereas it must be counter-clockwise.

Comment: [maybe this is helpful](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html)?

Comment: @prisoner849 I am decently sure that my points are in counterclockwise order. You can see in [the points](https://pastebin.com/TpML3Cve), at least from the first set of 3 points that form face 0 in [this diagram](https://imgur.com/a/IL5iig6),  that the points are arranged in a counter-clockwise rotation.

Comment: I did read the article suggested by @gman, and you can see my attempt at utilizing normals in my original question in which it had no effect with or without "geometry.computeVertexNormals()". On another note, even after reading the article that gman suggested and several other articles, there is no information on the what or how BufferGeometry constructs faces. I'm familiar with the [STL file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)). Does BufferGeometry assume that a set of 3 points is a face and continues that every set of 3 is a face?

Comment: As an easier check @prisoner849 , [here](https://pastebin.com/zP3ZeaPs) is the code used to make the first face, where row and col are referencing the position of the center of the diagram.

Comment: Yes, in your case, as you don't use `.index` property, your geometry is so-called a "triangle soup" (in terms of three.js it's "non-indexed buffer geometry"), which means that three vertices from `.position` attribute form a face.

Comment: @prisoner849 I did figure it out - if the points that I commented earlier are counterclockwise, my points needed to be in clockwise order. Do you have any idea why this is? Do the normals follow the left-hand-rule, because I had thought that it followed the right hand rule?